# начал учить С# и задался вопрос где лучше?

Tags: c#

Всем привет,вот буквально 2-3 дня назад сел за изучение С# и появился встречный вопрос: где учить его? В книгах,либо в видео? Если в книгах,то в каких. Если в видео,то на каком канале?
Хотелось бы какой-то материал на понятном языком и с задачами по темам в конце каждого раздела.
Заранее благодарю вас)

Comment: [Джон Скит!](https://www.google.com/search?q=c%23+in+depth&oq=c%23+in+de&aqs=chrome.0.0j69i58j69i57j0l3.2585j0j4&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)

Answer (score 0):

Есть довольно хорошая книга – Михаил Фленов "Библия C#". Написано подробно, понятно и с юмором. Думаю, для новичка самое то.

Также могу посоветовать хорошие электронный ресурс [здесь](https://metanit.com/sharp/) и видеокурс [здесь](https://proglib.io/p/learning-c-sharp/).